# Посоветуйте хоршую книгу по программированию не поверхностную, но глубокую

Tags: c++, книги

Есть "Совершенный код". Читал "Язык C++" Струструпа. Ещё кучу книг читал и плохих и хороших.

Что-нибудь похожее бы на "Искусство программирования" Кнута! Вот именно такое...
Пожалуйста, подскажите что-нибудь хорошее. Глубокое, а не поверхностное.

Спрашиваю, потому что боюсь опять потратить деньги на плохую книгу.

Интересующие языки: C++.

Также интересуют такие темы как ИИ, да и математика вообще.

Спасибо.

Comment: Каждую неделю кто-нибудь задает этот вопрос. Либо люди не пользуются поиском, либо поиск не очень хорош. Посмотрите [эту тему](http://hashcode.ru/questions/178607/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=178670#178670).

Comment: Привыкай читать с монитора(на крайний случай, купи себе ридер). И дешевле, и скорее привыкнешь находить и использовать не структурированную информацию в инете.

Answer (score 3):

Для глубокой промывки мозгов почитайте по метапрограммированию в С++ [Advanced C++ Metaprogramming by Davide Di Gennaro](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1460966163) и [C++ Template Metaprogramming: Concepts, Tools, and Techniques from Boost and Beyond by David Abrahams](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321227255).

Comment: Минуснувший, открой личико

Comment: Наверняка какой-нибудь хейтер англоязычной литературы.

Comment: Скорее, какой-то ярый ненавистник метапрограммирования.

Comment: +1, хоть я и недолюбливаю метапрограммирование в том виде, как оно реализовано в С++.

Comment: А оно там вообще никак не реализовано. Оно было случайно открыто как неожиданное свойство шаблонов. 

На практике следует пользоваться с осторожностью, однако, красивая штука!

Answer (score 2):

То ли я стал таким привередливым, то ли в самом деле интересно писать перестали. Почти все книги толстенные и какие-то тягомотные. Правда, подозреваю, что "Искусство программирования" Кнута тоже не пошло бы сейчас. А вот его же [Structured Programming With Goto Statements](http://bookfi.org/book/661212) перечитал с удовольствием.

За последние пару лет с удовольствие прочел только "Ядро Linux. Описание процесса разработки" Роберта Лав и может быть "Философия Java" Эккеля (и то, просто надо было по работе Java вспомнить).

А вот из "околософтовых", прочитанных недавно, понравился сборник интервью "Пионеры программирования. Диалоги с создателями наиболее популярных языков программирования" авторы  Федерико Бьянкуцци, Шейн Уорден.

Answer (score 1):

Если уж так не хотите потратить деньги зря, то скачайте энное количество книг для ознакомления, полистайте, а что понравится - купите. 
А если по сабжу, то люди Мейерса и Саттера рекомендуют. А некоторые - Александреску.

Answer (score 1):

Если интересует игровой ИИ - *Steve Rabin "AI Game Programming Wisdom"*.